# Apache Spark Orc file save takes too much time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

We are working on big data application with following steps :
1) Read a json file about 500 Mb size.
2) After some operations we are creating 5 orc files and save on hdfs.
If we save only 1 file it takes 80 seconds.
For orc save files we are using multithreading. The problem is 5 orc files save takes too much time approx 160 seconds.
our code is mentioned below.

```
    class SaveTask implements Runnable{
     private final String savePath;
     private Dataset<Row> data;
     public SaveTask(Dataset<Row> data, String savePath) {
      this.data = data;
      this.savePath = savePath;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {

        data.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).format("orc").partitionBy("choiceId").save(this.savePath);
        System.out.println("Saved in HDFS::: " + savePath);

    } catch (final Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

}
        The driver program is :

```
    public static void multiThreadRun(Dataset<Row> data){


    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Runnable task = new SaveTask(data, "hdfs:/user/root/AIR_MAIN/AIR"+i+".snappy.orc");
        executor.execute(task);
    }  
    executor.shutdown();
    // Wait until all threads are finish
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    System.out.println("Finished all threads");

}
```

our spark submit script is :

```
    ./bin/spark-submit \
    --class com.ibm.spark.etl.SparkCCNMainJsonProcessor --master yarn \
    --conf spark.driver.cores=4 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --executor-memory 6g \
    --num-executors 2 \
    /home/spark/deployment/multithreaded-spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

any help/suggestion regarding orc file save time optimization???